# Unity 2D, C# - Why my OnCollisionEnter2D doesn't collide?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i created two scripts, one named "Stats.cs" registers the player stats and the other one named "PlayerHealth.cs" "makes" the player take damage on contact and updates the Hearts in the HUD. My problem is, whenever i collide with an object that has a tag named "Projectile" it simply doesn't work, my player doesn't take damage at all. The Stats.cs script isn't in any object, the PlayerHealth.cs is in my Player object.

Stats.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Stats{

private int health;

public int maxHP = 3;

public int Health
{
    get
    {
        //Some code
        return health;
    }
    set
    {
        //Some code
        health = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxHP);
    }
}
public void SetHealth()
{
    Health = maxHP;
}
}
```

PlayerHealth.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
Stats playerStats = new Stats();

public int curHealth;
public int numOfHearts = 3;

public Image[] hearts;
public Sprite fullHeart;
public Sprite emptyHeart;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Projectile"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
        DamagePlayer(1);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

public void DamagePlayer(int damage)
{
    playerStats.Health -= damage;
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerStats.SetHealth();
    curHealth = numOfHearts;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    curHealth = playerStats.Health;
    numOfHearts = playerStats.maxHP;

    if (curHealth>numOfHearts){
        curHealth = numOfHearts;
    }
    if(curHealth <= 0){

        Die();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i < curHealth){
            hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
        } else
        {
            hearts[i].sprite = emptyHeart;
        }

        if(i < numOfHearts){
            hearts[i].enabled = true;
        } else {
            hearts[i].enabled = false;
        }

    }
}

void Die(){
    //Restart
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}


}
```

curHealth is updating so it will stay as the actual Health in Stats and will change the images in HUD.

The Player has a RigidBody2D on him two colliders, one is a box for the body, and the other is a circle collider, so when the player crouches, the circle collider disables.

The Projectiles also have and RigidBody2D with 0 gravity (so it won't fall in mid air) and a BoxCollider2D.

Comment: its not entirely clear from your post what is working what is not.

Comment: Is one of your collider a Trigger ? If so, ensure that in Project Settings>Physics>Collision matrix your layers are colliding, and "Queries Hit Trigger" is check. Plus use OnTriggerEnter2D instead of OnCollisionEnter2D

Comment: Does your `Debug.Log("Hello");` ever get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check and make sure that the projectile is tagged as Projectile and that the BoxCollider doesn't have "Is Trigger" checked.

I should also say, iterating with that for loop in the Update is very bad practice performance wise. That is happening literally as fast as the machine can loop it and it is doing that *every time*. I would look into updating it on an event.

Hope this helps!